# The Bounce Rate for my website fell to almost 0% overnight and I'm wondering why?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, google-analytics

I track analytics for my company's websites, and when I pulled up the October stats for one of them the Bounce Rate (percentage of single-page sessions in which there was no page interaction) was almost 0. Tracked it all the way back to a day a couple months ago where the stat disappeared overnight (see image)
[image: Sept Analytics Bounce Rate]

The website is managed on WordPress, and I'm pretty sure that date range lines up with the time we were going through and removing all non-essential blog posts older than a year. Could this have done something to kill our bounce rate? Is there some way I can check to see if my site is automatically redirecting users to a second page and killing the statistic? Anyone have any ideas or ever experienced this before?

**Additional Info:** Site is hosted on cPanel, built and managed in WordPress with the Sahifa theme. On the Google Analytics for the month, the Pages/Session grew almost exactly one whole page on average (2.37 to 3.36) and the Total Pageviews doubled (33,176 to 66,561). This makes me think there's some sort of automatic post-load redirect or something happening that tracks an initial pageview, then reloads the homepage again and counts it as a second pageview, or something crazy like that.

Comment: I saw this happen once when we had the anaylitcs.js script added to the site twice. You might check that its only being loaded once.

Comment: Can you post here and share with us page url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Google Analytics installed on website twice (with the same UA id). That's why your bounce rate fall down to near 0% and your pageviews doubled. First occurrence:

```
 <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=..."></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', '...');
</script>
```

And second one a little bit lower in code:

```
<!-- BEGIN ExactMetrics v5.3.9 Universal Analytics - https://exactmetrics.com/ -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', '...', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- END ExactMetrics Universal Analytics -->
```

Just remove one of them.

Comment: I see, yeah it looks like one of our program directors installed a Google Analytics plugin on the WordPress back end around that time too. Thanks so much!